# Фрагменты и бэкстек

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть два фрагмента. При смене добавляю в бэкстек. При нажатии кнопки - назад возвращается первый фрагмент. Необходимо отработать некий код, при этом. Как это сделать? onResume при возвращении не отрабатывает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если предположить, что проект небольшой, что есть некая activity, которой можно поручить управление fragments и их взаимодействием... вообщем совсем не элегантно и на скорую руку c кучей ограничений и неудобств и подойдет только для начала :)

Можно создать интерфейс, через который фрагменты будут общаться с активити

```
public interface OnFragmentEventListener {
    void onFragmentLifecycleEvent(String message);
...
    void onUserAction...
    void onData... 
...
}
```

абстрактный класс, от которого наследовать используемые фрагменты

```
abstract public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String TAG = "BaseFragment";

    private OnFragmentEventListener onFragmentEventListener ;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        if (context instanceof OnFragmentEventListener ) {
            fragmentEventListener = (OnFragmentEventListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement interface OnFragmentEventListener");
        }
    }
    final void onLifecycleEvent(String tag, String message) {
        if (onFragmentEventListener != null) {
            onFragmentEventListener.onFragmentLifecycleEvent(tag, message);
        }
    }
    protected void onFragmentLifecycleListener(String message) {
        if (fragmentEventListener != null) {
            fragmentEventListener.onFragmentLifecycleEvent(String tag, String message);
        }
    }

}
```

и потом во фрагментах, вызывать onLifecycleEvent в нужные моменты, события, к примеру:

```
public class AboutFragment extends BaseFragment {
    public static final String TAG = "AboutFragment";
...
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        onLifecycleEvent(TAG, "OnResume()");
    }
...
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        onLifecycleEvent(TAG, "OnPause()");
    }
...
```

Аctivity, "подписать" на эти события, реализовав интерфейс OnFragmentEventListener, например:

```
public class MainActivity extends MyActivity implements
       BaseFragment.OnFragmentEventListener {

   @Override
    public void onFragmentLifecycleEvent(String sender, String message) {
    //логика, что делать с полученными данными/событиями 
    }

private void clearBackStack() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
        fm.popBackStack(fm.getBackStackEntryAt(0).getId(),
                FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        fm.executePendingTransactions();
    }
}
```

... и "перекрыть" в ней же

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   //по разному реагировать на BackPressed в зависимости от ранее полученных данных, событий, работать с FragmentManager

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Решено**

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
manager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBackStackChanged() {
                    //code
                }
            });
```

К сожалению нельзя конкретизировать идет добавление в бэкстек или изьятие.